# Asterisk - Push-to-talk feature

Tags: asterisk

I would like to have a Push-to-Talk service deployed with Asterisk. The idea is that one user presses a button to talk/send a voice message to any other user or a group of users registered in asterisk.

Does anyone know if this is supported by Asterisk or how it could be implemented?

Any idea would be very welcome,
thanks for you help,
best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Other people call that paging or intercom.

Yes, it can be created in asterisk if destination stations/softphones support auto-answer.

For more info consult this page

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Paging+and+Intercom

Comment: Thanks a lot again arheops. I will investigate this paging and intercom function :)